# JS object to PHP, then INSERT via PDO

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pdo

I have this JS Object:

```
var planet = {
owner: 4,
name: "Mars",
loc: [3, 4],
level: 4,
baseIncome: 1000
}
```

I use ajax to transfer this object to PHP

```
postPlanets: function(planet){

    planet = JSON.stringify(planet);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "postGameData.php",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {planet: planet}, 
        error: ajax.error,
        success: ajax.success,
    });
```

I decode the JSON on php via

```
if (isset($_POST["planet"]{
    $planet = JSON_decode($_POST["planet"]);
}
```

I then try to do an INSERT using PDO

```
public function insertPlanet($planet){

    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("
        INSERT INTO planets
            (owner, name, x, y, level, baseIncome)
        VALUES
            (:owner, :name, :x, :y, :level, :baseIncome)
    ");

    $stmt->bindParam(":owner", $planet["owner"]);
    $stmt->bindParam(":name", $planet["name"]);
    $stmt->bindParam(":x", $planet["loc"][0]);
    $stmt->bindParam(":y", $planet["loc"][1]);
    $stmt->bindParam(":level", $planet["level"]);
    $stmt->bindParam(":baseIncome", $planet["baseIncome"]);

    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->errorCode() == 0){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But its not working.
I know it breaks once it tries to bind the very first parameter on PDO, but i dont know either way nor how i could possibly debug the prepared statement at all.

What am i doing wrong ?

ERROR RETURN

```
object(stdClass)#3 (5) {
  ["owner"]=>
  string(3) "sdf"
  ["name"]=>
  string(3) "sdf"
  ["loc"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    int(4)
  }
  ["level"]=>
  string(3) "sdf"
  ["baseIncome"]=>
  string(1) "f"
}
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in <b>D:\SecureWAMP_Portable\htdocs\projectX\DBManager.php</b> on line <b>285</b><br />
```

285 is the very first BIND attempt.

Comment: Your json object references ```location``` and you reference ```loc``` in your php. Look at ```var_dump($planet)``` to check what you want to insert/bind.

Comment: typo for this question.
Regardless, its not the error because the code breaks when trying to bind the first parameter ("owner")

Comment: Can you post the output of ```var_dump($plant)``` - you may still reference it wrong and thus the bind fails.

Comment: See OP edit, i added it.

Comment: You need to add **,true** to your `JSON_decode` call if you want to use it as an associative array. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's object I think you can call like `$planet->owner` not like array $planet['owner'].

Comment: Holy crap, so much wasted time for such a blatant error. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have decoded the data into an `stdObject` type, have it like the following:

```
if (isset($_POST["planet"]{
    $planet = JSON_decode($_POST["planet"], true);
}
```

This way you have the object as an array. `stdObject` means that you can access your data like: `$planet->owner` rather than `$planet["owner"]`. That's what the second `true` param for `json_decode` is used for.

Comment: Thanks. The other guy was quicker, but i gave you +1. Thanks !

Comment: No problem, though my solution works without having to modify any bit of your code.